# Uploading CICD artifact to Blob Storage with a time stamp

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, devops, cicd

So I'm working on a CI/CD Pipeline in Azure DevOps and I want to add the functionality of sending the artifact at every run to blob storage, so we can revert to it in case something goes wrong in future runs.

I can send the artifact to Blob storage using an Azure File Copy Task. The issue is, if I am to do it in this way, the file would be uploaded using the exact name of the artifact, so at each new run the newly created artifact would overwrite the old one in Blob storage. Would it be possible to add a timestamp on the name of the blob so that I have a history of all artifacts at each run and, in case I need to revert, I could look for exactly the artifact that I need? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use blob versioning -> [Blob versioning - Azure Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/versioning-overview) in this scenario